# Evernote API Change Alert Notification

Tags: api, evernote

When there is a new release with a version change, or any release that may cause deprecation, how are developers notified? is there an email list that we can sign up for?

I have been documenting this for almost 200 api's, some use twitter, some send alert emails, some rely on statuspage, admins who have created apps, and even some have no system at all. I am trying to find out how developers are notified when a new release to the evernote api is imminent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That hasn't really happened, deprecated APIs have been kept around so far and not actually removed. We do make changes in sdks though and remove deprecated methods in newer versions, as well as add new methods.